# PHP Session Storage and header("location:") Issue

Tags: php, session, header

I'm having trouble with session and header. First of all, they are both working on my local development computer. But after I published the website, they don't work there.

The first problem is about storing session data. I tried everything.

- I wrote `session_start()` at the top of the page.
- Checked if the folder is writable with `is_writable(session_save_path())` method. Which returns true.

But still not working.

Second is about `header("location: ")`. It works too on my localhost but not working on the server that I published the website.

What am I missing?

For example, at index.php, those lines don't work.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}
echo $_SESSION['counter'] ++;
?>
```

When I refresh the page, it doesn't increment the value.

Comment: Anything in the error log? What is the production set-up like? "doesn't work there" meaning the sessions aren't persistent, or not being set at all?

Comment: "Not working" is not a workable problem description. Figure out and describe in more detail **what you're doing** and what it **does or doesn't do**. Have you activated error reporting? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Having said that, you're very likely looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/476

Comment: I added error_reporting( E_ALL ); at the top but returns nothing.

Comment: Have you also added `ini_set('display_errors', true)`? Otherwise you won't see nothing.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

It seems the white spaces before session_start() were causing the problem. Removed them and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

I would check your page encoding.  If you have notepad++ (if you don't, download it because it's awesome) use it to open the page and click encoding to see what it is.  Make sure it is UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I changed the encoding but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I see the white space was your issue.  My appologies, I assumed that you checked that already.  The BOM issue is a more common pitfall.